# Can a person add CORS headers using the ELB Application Load Balancer (sitting in front of Solr)?

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, solr, cors, amazon-elb

We have a number of EC2 instances running Solr in EC2, which we've used in the past through another application. We would like to move towards allowing users (via web browser) to directly access Solr.

Without something "in front" of Solr this results in a security risk, so we have opted to try to use ELB (specifically the Application Load Balancer) as a simple and maintenance free way of preventing certain requests from hitting SOLR (i.e. preventing the public from DELETING or otherwise modifying the documents in Solr).

This worked great, but we realize that we need to deal with the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) issue. In other words, we need to add the appropriate headers to requests that come in from a browser. I have not yet seen a way of doing this with Application Load Balancer but am wondering if it is possible to do someway. If it is not possible, I would love as an additional recomendation the easier and least complicated way of adding these headers. We really really really hate to add something like nginx in front of Solr because then we've got additional redundancy to deal with, more servers, etc.

Thank you!

Comment: *"preventing the public from DELETING or otherwise modifying the documents in Solr"* ... how does ALB fix this for you?  Is it just the fact that something like `GET /solr/select?...` is the mechanism for reading while other paths are used for modifying, and only that path is enabled in the ALB? (since ALB allows path-based routing) Is your application also behind an ELB (or ALB)?  Or CloudFront?  (Either of which could be leveraged to make cross-origin unnecessary.)

Comment: Using API Gateway you may expose only the paths and HTTP methods you need to, and protect the rest of the API.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much I can find on CORS for ALB either and I remember when I used Beanstalk with ELB I had to add CORS support in my java application directly.

Having said that, I can find a lot of articles on how to set up CORS for [Solr](http://marianoguerra.org/posts/enable-cors-in-apache-solr.html).
Can it be an option for you?